# Gmail display broken image from my one ubuntu server

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, gmail, lamp

I have live server with ubuntu 15.4 installation. And am working with PHP. For that i am using LAMP. In system for firewall ufw is there.

> I am facing problem: Images i send from my server in gmail email(web,
>   mobile App) it's broken (404 error). But in thunderbird, mac, and also
>   in yahoo, it display properly.

I tried this with another server, from that server i send email it will display in gmail properly.

I have tried every solution from google, But i can't figure out what is wrong with me. i am searching for this from last 6 days.

I have same problem like here and tried all suggestions given here [Gmail's new image caching is breaking image links in newsletter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903967/gmails-new-image-caching-is-breaking-image-links-in-newsletter)

I have referred all forums of google. My doubt is, it may be because of some my server restriction, but i can't figure out. I have also tried after disable firewall. But still not.

I was able to view images in gmail email up to 13th December 2015, after onwards it stop displaying. on 15th December again i was able to view images. But after that it stopped, and currently it's not displaying.

I have also tried with different permission, user and group.

My /etc/default/ufw settings are

```
# Set to yes to apply rules to support IPv6 (no means only IPv6 on loopback
# accepted). You will need to 'disable' and then 'enable' the firewall for
# the changes to take affect.
IPV6=yes

# Set the default input policy to ACCEPT, DROP, or REJECT. Please note that if
# you change this you will most likely want to adjust your rules.
DEFAULT_INPUT_POLICY="DROP"

# Set the default output policy to ACCEPT, DROP, or REJECT. Please note that if
# you change this you will most likely want to adjust your rules.
DEFAULT_OUTPUT_POLICY="ACCEPT"

# Set the default forward policy to ACCEPT, DROP or REJECT.  Please note that
# if you change this you will most likely want to adjust your rules
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"

# Set the default application policy to ACCEPT, DROP, REJECT or SKIP. Please
# note that setting this to ACCEPT may be a security risk. See 'man ufw' for
# details
DEFAULT_APPLICATION_POLICY="SKIP"

# By default, ufw only touches its own chains. Set this to 'yes' to have ufw
# manage the built-in chains too. Warning: setting this to 'yes' will break
# non-ufw managed firewall rules
MANAGE_BUILTINS=no

#
# IPT backend
#
# only enable if using iptables backend
IPT_SYSCTL=/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf

# Extra connection tracking modules to load. Complete list can be found in
# net/netfilter/Kconfig of your kernel source. Some common modules:
# nf_conntrack_irc, nf_nat_irc: DCC (Direct Client to Client) support
# nf_conntrack_netbios_ns: NetBIOS (samba) client support
# nf_conntrack_pptp, nf_nat_pptp: PPTP over stateful firewall/NAT
# nf_conntrack_ftp, nf_nat_ftp: active FTP support
# nf_conntrack_tftp, nf_nat_tftp: TFTP support (server side)
IPT_MODULES="nf_conntrack_ftp nf_nat_ftp nf_conntrack_netbios_ns"
```

Out-put from sudo ufw status is:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache                     ALLOW       Anywhere
1433                       ALLOW       Anywhere
3306/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
25/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Apache (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
1433 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
25/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

3306/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

I am using SMTP.

Any other information required from my server settings let me know.

Thanks.