# Static google map image doesn't work in mail

Tags: html, email, html-email

I am trying to use a static google map image inside an email but this not seem to work

The html before

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=21.16450299999999984379,-86.82787199999999927513&amp;zoom=13&amp;size=300x200&amp;maptype=roadmap&amp;markers=color:blue%7Clabel:●%7C21.16450299999999984379,-86.82787199999999927513">
```

[image]

And this is what I get inside the email

```
<img src="https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/gQDzMmZ7RpNDj4Mdp7XBbc5UbVvXcJgNcEASXCMlVjrliobUSZFDgceGTx3rkHW2E3Q1pz0JVpnMFtvMrY_gjErKKr5opfX37TKavPZV8bL1XqIalyELzTByTaRbIMGY_o7hqpGeJiTXnw9GlyqFTfXZEkZKZLEVn7f3PLODN7IsZwzvbGC881AvbbhZsbrXDs_jnHhgcxHXK1M_XybeRl-IUe9wga3-WYv4mWmavneZqlTIJ32xkAZE6FewG6HHTxy8iMa7lnKAMSIyzTCrKQ7zoumeB-l7R3H6sazJLNeKBgvZYH7nIQ9fvOilZXQOlVWSKw=s0-d-e1-ft#https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=21.16450299999999984379,-86.82787199999999927513&amp;zoom=13&amp;size=300x200&amp;maptype=roadmap&amp;markers=color:blue%7Clabel:●%7C21.16450299999999984379,-86.82787199999999927513" class="CToWUd a6T" tabindex="0">
```

image not found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gmail's new image caching is breaking image links in newsletter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903967/gmails-new-image-caching-is-breaking-image-links-in-newsletter)

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. You can image capture it and embed that and then under put a link to the map if you want people to use it interactively.

Comment: @MattW. All my images are working excepted the static google map, probably because there is no extension ...