# Inserting an image from local directory in spring framework in html img tag(spring boot)

Tags: html, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to insert an image from my local directory which is in 
`resources` folder, full path is `resources\images\logo-2.png`

[image]

My dynamic html is `<img src="resources/images/logo-2.png" alt="logo">`

and in my final output it gives me this

```
<img src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2uoPI9RTChl3eYeKfRBGfR4AtNAs6Xuk5rrSPz9dDmyyXgeq4dj_pxg9VWqI4lhsiL60IRKAjnw=s0-d-e1-ft#http://resources/images/logo-2.png" alt="logo" class="CToWUd">
```

I dont know whats that initial url is, but i am not getting the image from my path.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903967/gmails-new-image-caching-is-breaking-image-links-in-newsletter

Answer (score 0):

You could always try outsourcing using the IP address as your route instead?

`<img src="http://192.0.0.1/resources/images/logo-2.png" alt="logo">` //change 192.0.0.1 to whatever your local route is.

depending on how you have your webserver is set up it may just not support local casting to directory.