# How to clear cached images in gmail proxy server

Tags: html, gmail

I am sending HTML content in email. Inside the HTML I have some thing like

`<img src="https://example.com/logo.png" border="0" alt="Logo" class="styleclass">`

when I open in gmail and yahoo, it is showing correct image.
I replaced the image in server with same name and I am sending emails again.
In yahoo it is showing new image, but in gmail it is showing old image.
I searched about it and I came to know, google stores images in proxy server when we open first time, and from the next time it will show the image from its proxy server. If I change image name in link, it may show correct image. But I can not change my link. I'd like to know if anyone ever came across this and if so, how it was solved.

In gmail, my code is modified as below.

`<img src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/4sG5UHo-nA6ZlKKtDIWy8f9hKIVM9bM9uBFsS_0HI8yEuKaCfxH695uj5VpUAEUahDmSTEOyJVu76V5Zdz2bi28=s0-d-e1-ft#https://example.com/logo.png" border="0" alt="Logo" class="styleclass">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change image name and reupload it. Google proxies has catche which saves image, so when anything change with domain it can lead to incorrect url.

I checked this post and it helped me today:
[Gmail's new image caching is breaking image links in newsletter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903967/gmails-new-image-caching-is-breaking-image-links-in-newsletter)