# Images not visible in Gmail sent through HTML

Tags: java, html, css

I am trying to send mails to user who signup through our portal. Everything works fine except that image is not visible in the mail. here is the snippet of code

```
<html>
<body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0" bgcolor='#E5E5E5' >


<STYLE>
 .headerTop { background-color:#FFCC66; border-top:0px solid #000000; border-bottom:1px solid #FFFFFF; text-align:center; }
 .adminText { font-size:10px; color:#996600; line-height:200%; font-family:verdana; text-decoration:none; }
 .headerBar { background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top:0px solid #333333; border-bottom:10px solid #FFFFFF; }
 .title { font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; color:#295EA0; font-family:arial; line-height:110%; }
 .subTitle { font-size:11px; font-weight:normal; color:#666666; font-style:italic; font-family:arial; }
 .defaultText { font-size:12px; color:#000000; line-height:150%; font-family:arial; }
 .footerRow { background-color:#FFFFCC; border-top:10px solid #FFFFFF; }
 .footerText { font-size:10px; color:#996600; line-height:100%; font-family:verdana; }
 a { color:#00F; color:#00F; color:#00F; }
</STYLE>



<table width="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" class="backgroundTable" bgcolor='#E5E5E5' >
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="center">


<table width="550" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">


<tr>
<td style="background-color:#FFFFFF;border-top:0px solid #333333;border-bottom:10px solid #FFFFFF;"><center><a href=""><IMG id=editableImg1 SRC="#banner#" BORDER="0" title="Reppify"  alt="Reppify" align="center"></a></center></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Also when I remove the google proxy address from the path of my images, it is visible in email. I was wondering if its a issue og google proxy servers??

Comment: why is your image code in all caps `<IMG>` its safer to have it lowercase. also the source says `SRC="#banner#"` it does onto link to an image on a server. You will also need to host the image somewhere. so that the user can link to it and download it into the email

Comment: E-mails support very limited CSS, let alone any external resources. Backgrounds should be placed as `<img>` and in most cases require the user to allow external content for it to load.

Comment: I converted <IMG> tags to lowecase but still doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML image not showing in Gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437916/html-image-not-showing-in-gmail)

Comment: Another possibility - can the google image proxy server fetch your image?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491590/image-links-broken-in-gmail-because-of-googles-image-proxy

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write the image full path

```
<tr>
<td style="background-color:#FFFFFF;border-top:0px solid #333333;border-bottom:10px solid #FFFFFF;"><center><a href=""><IMG id=editableImg1 SRC="**http://www.www.com/banner.jpg**" BORDER="0" title="Reppify"  alt="Reppify" align="center"></a></center></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need to give dynamic path which i am taking from java code, so i can't give path static as yo suggest.